# Removed current shell caused stuck at loading screen

Tags: shell, zsh, login

I've got a problem with my Linux PC, it is running Bodhi Linux which is based on Ubuntu, so here's what I think provoked the problem:

A few days ago I installed `zsh` and made it my default shell but not long after that commands like `mv`, `ls` would display something like: *mv command not found*, so I thought I would change the default shell back to bash.
I uninstalled `zsh` then I changed the shell using `chsh`. After I restarted my PC everything seemed fine, I logged in but after that all I would get would be a loading screen without a loading bar. I tried logging in a console interface using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I tried loggining from there too but it would output a error message in the blink of a second then prompt me again to log in, I think I saw the word *zsh* in it. I tried going in recovery mode to change the default shell but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should first changed then remove, you can change it with root account for example to `bash` with `chsh -s /bin/bash YOUR_USERNAME_HERE`

Comment: Moved to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should first changed then remove, you can change it with *root* account for example to `bash` with login to one of ttys (to tty1,
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

```
chsh -s /bin/bash YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
```